# Can I use my driver's license for domestic travel within Mexico if I arrived in Mexico with my passport?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, mexico, domestic-travel

I am a UK citizen. I hold valid UK and Nigerian passports, and valid UK and California driver's licenses. I am flying from LA to Mexico City to renew my US work visa, and the embassy will take my passport for a few days.

Can I use my US/UK license, or Nigerian passport, to fly from Mexico City to Cancún and back while I wait for my passport to be returned?

Answer (score 2):

Your Nigerian passport will definitely be fine. As for your driving licences, possibly, depending on the check-in clerk, but again your Nigerian passport is definitely OK.